# How to display variable as text on screen in Android Studio 1.1.0

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-studio, gps

I'm having as issue with displaying text on screen on the emulator. I'm using the Google Maps API and want to display the distance between two locations on screen.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
public static double distanceBetween(double startLat, double startLong, double endLat, double endLong)
{

    float[] result  = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(startLat, startLong, endLat, endLong, result);
    return (double)result[0];


}
```

Comment: When working with Google Maps and GCM, make sure to test on real device. Don't rely on emulator's results.

Comment: I'm currently manually setting the location markers for testing purposes. Once the code is in place, i'll test it with a physical device

Comment: Are you showing route map? Where do you want to show the distance?

Comment: im showing the actual map, yes. But not the routes or addresses yet. Top right if possible

Comment: Put a `TextView` in the layout file and set the output of `distanceBetween` to that `TextView`.

Comment: TextView is a class?

Comment: I tried using TextView but in the java file and now the entire app crashes.

Comment: For calculate `distance` and `display` them of the map, you can use `android-maps-utils` [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/#spherical). Also [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) is source code demo, one called `computeDistanceBetween` you can try it on.